# How to use download openstreetmap file to serve a local map app?

Tags: openstreetmap

I have download a partial area data file (OSM format) to local. I have a local server which not connect to internet. So I want to build a local map app only with local OSM file (I use OpenLayer js).

I searched openstreetmap.org wiki, but find no solution.

Is there any way or documentaton to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By "local" you mean local on your machine or a local web server?

First you need to generate map tiles. Then you prepare the map HTML, including the OpenLayers code. The tile URL should point to your tiles (in case of a local machine, just use the "file://" protocol for URLs).

Here's one way how you can generate tiles (you can skip some of the steps): http://braincrunch.tumblr.com/post/9921938947/maperitive-tutorial-a-hiking-web-map-in-ten-easy-steps

Answer (score 1):

1) i have to create an API that connects to a locally downloaded openstreet map and does to following:
2) Given a GPS location display the location on the map. 
3) Be able to display the route to the location and update while the individual is on the move.

Numbers 2) and 3) are not yet my problem. number 1) is my problem for now. i don't even know where to start. i have been searching but still saw nothing i can understand.

what i want to know is: where to download OSM that i would be able to use locally? an example or a tutorial on an API that connects to the map locally and able to display it(and maybe able to zoom in, zoom out)?

the API can be in java, c#, or c++. but any other language is welcome as i have no choice.